# How to have a variable available across my whole app in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, angularjs-service, multilingual

So I'm currently trying to create a bilingual site in angularjs. I'm doing a simple ng-if, so if my variable equals one value it shows one language if it equals the other it shows the translation. I have a button in my nav bar that toggles between the different languages, but it seems that the service variable isn't being updated inside each controller when changed. This is the service

```
angular.module('core.lc').factory('LangChoice', function() {
    var langOptions = ["Chinese", "English"];
    var langPos = 0;
    /* what a function */
    function switchLang() {
        if (langPos == 0) {
            langPos = 1;
        }
        else {
            langPos = 0;
        }
        return langPos;
    }

    return {
        langPos: langPos,
        langOptions: langOptions,
        switchLang: switchLang
    };
});
```

When the service was created it was resolved by the value the function returned by the issue i'm having now is finding a way for each controller to monitor the langPos value since only one controller is triggering the function. Any help would be welcome, Thank you. If there's an easier or more efficient way to create a bilingual site please let me know.

Comment: `function switchLang() { langPos = 1 - langPos; return langPos; }`

Comment: Have you considered creating a filter? Then you can do something like this:  `ng-if="'English' | isLanguageSet"`

Comment: Another simple way to do translation is to create a filter that takes in a given string and returns the translated string. Example: <h1>{{ $ctrl.title | translate }}</h1>. The translate filter would internally work out which language is currently set etc

Answer (score 0):

Usually we create seperate files for each Language keywords. When we need to take decision on the basis of language we just fetch keywords from the language selected and simply use them on page.

STEPS

1. Create data service in a seperate module which will fetch data from seperate language files.
2. Bind data returned from service into objects and simply return.
3. Take reference of the service into UI module and simply use the objects(UI module responsibilty is just to show data).

Data objects returning responsibility is now at data service only.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this for the most part. What I'm saying is my navbar is its own component, which is where the language button is. When I click it to change the language the rest of my templates in the ng-view don't get updated cause no event was triggered to reset the value. Is there a way to make sure all the components get notified of the change?

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly sudo code but it should give you an idea of how to go about with this. This is not intended to be a copy and paste solution;

You should create a hash/dictionary of your translations and create a filter that would take in a string and return the translated string.

```
    Example of your HTML template:
        <h1>{{ $ctrl.title | translate }}</h1>

        Example of your relevant controller/directive:
        this.title = "Hello" // This would be your default language

        Example of the angularjs filter you need to create:
        const LANGUAGE_SET = "ZH"; // This needs to be set whenever you change your language and should be stored somewhere you globally. 

// These are your translations with the default language being the key.
        const Translations = {
            "Hello": {
                    "EN": "Hello",
                    "ZH" "你好",
                }
        }


    app.filter('translate',   function translate(original) {
            return Translations[original][LANGUAGE_SET];
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watch on your LangChoice service like

```
$rootScope.$watch('LangChoice.myObject', function(newVal){
  console.log('data changes into: ', newVal)
}, true);
```

Return myObject from your service i.e. bind all individual property within myObject and watch it on your controllers.
Hope it works.